# How to properly use crypto/rsa Decrypt function in golang?

Tags: go, rsa

```
func (priv *PrivateKey) Decrypt(rand io.Reader, ciphertext []byte, opts crypto.DecrypterOpts) (plaintext []byte, err error)
```

Above is a function from golang crypto/rsa library. 
I don't quite understand the explanation to the argument *opts* here.

> Decrypt decrypts ciphertext with priv. If opts is nil or of type
>   *PKCS1v15DecryptOptions then PKCS#1 v1.5 decryption is performed. Otherwise opts must have type *OAEPOptions and OAEP decryption is
>   done.

I wonder what opts value should I pass into this function?

Comment: "what opts value should I pass into this function?" That depends on, as the documentation you quoted clearly states, whether you need PKCS decryption, or OAEP decryption. Since no information about what you're trying to accomplish is given in the question, no one will be able to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

The `DecryptOpts` can be one of:

- [OAEPOptions](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#OAEPOptions)
- [PKCS1v15DecryptOptions](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#PKCS1v15DecryptOptions)

Depending on which you passed in, `rsa.Decrypt` will call [DecryptOAEP](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#DecryptOAEP) or [DecryptPKCS1v15](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#DecryptPKCS1v15) (with or without session key).

You can find examples for how to use those options in the [rsa package examples](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#pkg-examples).

Which options you want to use depends entirely on the padding chosen at encryption time.

In the future, you can always look at the [source for rsa.Decrypt](https://golang.org/src/crypto/rsa/rsa.go?#L111), it's pretty clear what it can handle.